# .net core3 grpc serverside streaming forever

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, http2, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm fairly new to the whole Grpc, so I was wondering if it is Ok to never close a Grpc streaming request and keep it open forever, something like putting it in a `while(true)`
my main concerns here are performance, socket-exhaustion, and viability in the long run production scenario?

Comment: What is the actual scenario here? Is there an "await Task.Delay" periodically?

Comment: yes, there can be a delay. actually, I just want to do sth like server push. the client starts a grpc call, but server never ends it, at the server-side, I want to have an infinite loop, so whenever the server needs to push something to the client can send the data through this grpc channedl

Comment: that's pretty much the typical scenario for a server-streaming response, then; you should be fine

Comment: It's ok to have long lived streaming RPC requests (and gRPC is good for handling those), but there are some additional considerations compared to short-lived unary RPCs. I'd highly recommend this talk that gives a very good summary of what to expect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Naonb2XD_2Q&feature=youtu.be